# What Eye of Talos was the guard talking about?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went to Windhelm one day and a guard mentioned "an Eye of Talos was a fine ship, but now it's in wrecks. It's north of here." Then the map updated. I looked at the map above Windhelm but there was no Eye of Talos. What did the guard mean by the ship's name?

Answer (score 5):

The wreck in question is actually ["The Pride of Tel Vos"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wreck_of_The_Pride_of_Tel_Vos). Per the notes section:

> During a random conversation with a Windhelm guard, the wreck is referred to as "The Eye of Talos". The map marker is still added correctly, however.

It is unclear whether this was a mistake made while recording the line, the name of the ship was changed some time after the line was recorded, or this is a case of the [telephone game](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_(game)) ("Pride of Tel Vos" does sound somewhat similar to "Eye of Talos").